# Convert List<MyDTO> to List<Map<String,String>> using Gson

Tags: java, gson

I have DTO as below :

```
     public class MyDTO {
           private String MEValueName;
           private String MyId;

          // getters and setters

     }

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     List<MyDTO> list = new ArrayList<MyDTO>();
     MyDTO dto = new MyDTO();

     dto.setMEValueName("raghu");
     dto.setMyId("qwer");

     MyDTO dto1 = new MyDTO();

     dto1.setMEValueName("raghuveer");
     dto1.setMyId("qwer1");

     list.add(dto);
     list.add(dto1);

     String json = gson.toJson(list);
     System.out.println(json);

     // below line is failing
     List<Map<String, String>> list1 = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType()); 
     System.out.println(list1);
```

when i run this i get the follow error :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 11 path $[0].`

Also i want to use a generic type so that i can use other DTOs also to convert to list of map. Kindly suggest.

Comment: what is wrong with the question what am i missing ?

Comment: It is just a plain POJO

Comment: Could you provide the code for MyDTO?

Comment: what is going to be the map contents?

Comment: The DTOs in the list that we pass

Comment: @Raghuveer but the map is only having String rt? and what will be the map key ?

Comment: @Jobin the key will be the field names of the POJO

Comment: @Raghuveer ???? fieldNames?

Comment: @Jobin updated the POJO lets forget CId POJO for now

Comment: Your code works well for me.  The results are `[{"MEValueName":"raghu","MyId":"qwer"},{"MEValueName":"raghuveer","MyId":"qwer1"}]
` and `[{MEValueName=raghu, MyId=qwer}, {MEValueName=raghuveer, MyId=qwer1}]`.

Comment: what version of gson you are using ?

Comment: @Raghuveer I just tested it myself and works as expected with jdk1.8.0_121 and Gson 2.8.1 !?

Comment: am using 2.3.1 does that make a difference ?

Comment: I don't think so, I downloaded Gson 2.3.1 and it works the same, maybe try your own example in your question and create a clean project with that and test yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I see two immediate problems...
The json-string is of an object of type List<MyDTO>.
gson.fromJson must have a TypeToken of that same object type.
And even if the fromJson worked, you cant assign List<MyDTO> to a list of type List<Map<String,String>>.

Edit (doing this by memory so it might need some fine tuning to compile):

```
List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new List();
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
list1.add(map);
map.add("some key",json);
```

Comment: does that mean `Gson` does not have a solution to my problem ? am i missing something ?

Comment: Gson just converts the object back and forth via a json string.

Comment: Depends on what you need the map for? It's <string, string>, do you want the DTO represented as a json string in the map?

Comment: yup, List<DTO> to List<Map<String, String>>